# Disabling websockets in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

My `webview` opens a site that as something like this:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(placeToConnect);
ws.onopen = function onOpen(evt) {
  ws.send("test message");
};

ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
  //Do something with evt.data
  ws.close();
  ws = null;
};
ws.onerror = function(evt) {
  //Do something
};
```

I've overriden all `webview` methods and none is called when the socket communication happens (Ajax request can be intercepted in the `onShouldInterceptRequest` method)

How do we disable `WebSockets` in a `WebView`?

Comment: have you tried `webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);`?

Comment: @Niraj yes. The connection is also maintained.